# What I am missing in order filtering against query parameter in url to work in Django Rest Framework?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I was trying to implement function filtering against query parameter in url following [this page](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/filtering/) and it worked in other environment.
Thus, I tried to replicate this code in other application. However, even though I implemented same code, cannot find filtering interface as below.
Does anyone know what I am missing?
[image]

**urls.py**

```
router=routers.SimpleRouter()
router.register(r'list',projectViewSet)
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^api/', include(router.urls)),
]
```

**views.py**

```
class projectViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):

    """
    This API returns the list of all projects with basic information to be able to filter
    """
    queryset=html.objects.all()
    serializer_class = projectSerializer
    filter_class=projectAPIfilter
```

**serializer.py**

```
class projectSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    area=areaSerializer(read_only=True)
    unmet=unmetSerializer(read_only=True)
    energy = energySer(read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = html
        fields = ('pk', 'project', 'version', 'program', 'location', 'certificate', 'user', 'good', 'final','area','unmet','energy','good','final')
```

**filters.py**

```
class projectAPIfilter(filters.FilterSet):
    user = django_filters.CharFilter(lookup_expr="iexact")
    project = django_filters.CharFilter(lookup_expr="icontains")

    class Meta:
        model=html
        fields=['project','program','location','certificate','user','good','final']
```

**settings.py**

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_FILTER_BACKENDS': (
        'django_filters.rest_framework.DjangoFilterBackend',
    ),
    'DEFAULT_PAGINATION_CLASS': 'rest_framework.pagination.LimitOffsetPagination',
    'PAGE_SIZE': 100
}

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.humanize',
    'corsheaders',
    'rest_framework',
    'rest_framework.authtoken',
    'widget_tweaks',
    'crispy_forms',
    'rest_framework_swagger',
    #'el_pagination',
    'django_tables2',
    'django_filters',
    'heatBalance',
    'project',
    'ecm',
    'help',
    'BEAM',
    'social_django',
    # 'social_django_mongoengine'
]
```

**packages**

```
django=2.0.4=py35_0  
djangorestframework==3.8.2
django-filter==1.1.0
```

**Update**
According to Angela's query, I tried to type /project/api/list/?user=existing-user-uuid, but seems api return doesn't change as below.
[image]

Comment: Can you add the versions of DRF,Django,django-filter?

Comment: I have added versions of DRF,Django,django-filter. Is this version problem?

Comment: Why are you still using `DRF 0.1.0` ?? Even the **`DRF==3.7.7`** is available?

Comment: I have updated djangorestframework==3.8.2 as above. But the problem is not solved yet. Do you have any idea what could cause this problem?

Comment: I tried to reproduce the problem. But failed. Can you tell me how can I reproduce it?

Comment: Does this `/project/api/list/?user=**existing-user-uuid**  in your browser return any results?

Comment: @Angela I tried your suggestion, but seems return doesn't change as shown above

Comment: @JPG You mean you didnt' have any problem?

Comment: Yeah. Exactly. Is there any way I could reproduce the error?

Comment: @KatsuyaObara so you are saying, if you have tried filtering using your filter fields and the filtering is not working?

Answer (score 0):

I tried to define filter backend in views.py explicitly as below. Then the problem solved as below image. Still dont know why specifying in settings.py doesnt work. But in case someone has same problem, this could be one way to solve it.
[image]
**views.py**

```
class projectViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):

    """
    This API returns the list of all projects with basic information to be able to filter
    """
    queryset=html.objects.all()
    serializer_class = projectSerializer
    filter_class=projectAPIfilter
    filter_backends = (django_filters.rest_framework.DjangoFilterBackend,)
    pagination_class = projectPagination
```

**pagination.py**

```
from rest_framework.pagination import PageNumberPagination

class projectPagination(PageNumberPagination):
    page_size = 100
```